# Linear Non-Linear Modeling

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions, linearmodels

So I've included code for 1 question for reference below.

Question 3 asks me to assume that the linear predictor, takes the values between −5 and 5 equally spaced by 0.01. If the link function is logit, **log (μi/(1-μi)) = x_i^t β**, then compute and plot the mean response against the linear predictor, x_i^t β.

```
#Q3
LinearPredictor <- seq(-5,5,0.01)
head(LinearPredictor)
# compute inverse of link function
link_func <- function(x) exp(x)

# Compute mean response
MeanResponse<- as.vector(link_func(LinearPredictor))

# Plot the values
plot(LinearPredictor, MeanResponse)
```

For the next question, I'm asked the same thing but to assume that the link function is inverse negative and I'm not sure how to approach this piece. I attempted having the link_func as

```
link_func <- 1/-(function(x) exp(x))
```

But I kept getting a binary operator error.

Any advice? I'm new to this subject.

Thank You

Comment: You have to start your custom function builds with `function(x)`. Here you are nesting within a denominator.

Comment: @Phil can you clarify? I'm not sure what you mean by custom function builds. Does this make sens? It worked in R (link_func <- function(x) 1/-exp(x))

Comment: I mean that `1/-(function(x) exp(x))` will not work. But `function(x) 1/-exp(x)` will.